# Assigning multiple matrix values to single column of data frame

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have the following data frame with info for 163 monkeys:

```
> head(vervetdf)
    ucla_id                  country                             species Gender pi
1   A8516_M_2                 Barbados                 Chlorocebus sabaeus      M NA
2   AG23_F_10                 Tanzania Chlorocebus pygerythrus pygerythrus      F NA
3  AG5417_F_10                 Tanzania Chlorocebus pygerythrus pygerythrus      F NA
4  AGM126_F_1 Central African Republic               Chlorocebus tantalus       F NA
5  AGM127_F_1 Central African Republic                Chlorocebus tantalus      F NA
6  AGM129_F_1 Central African Republic                Chlorocebus tantalus      F NA

> str(vervetdf)
'data.frame':   163 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ucla_id: Factor w/ 163 levels "A8516_M_2","AG23_F_10",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8        9 10 ...
 $ country: Factor w/ 12 levels "Barbados","Botswana",..: 1 11 11 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ species: Factor w/ 5 levels "Chlorocebus aethiops aethiops",..: 4 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Gender : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ pi     : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I need to add the pi values for each monkey for analysis and plotting, so I created the new column pi. Pi is the same for all monkeys of the same species (I have 5 species), but is calculated in windows, so there are 1300 pi values for each monkey. I have a matrix with the pi values for each species:

```
> head(corrected_pi)
          pi1         pi2         pi3         pi4         pi5
w1.ce 0.001918322 0.002408772 0.002306475 0.002086117 0.002501300
w2.ce 0.002125624 0.002779025 0.002620691 0.002599817 0.002847614
w3.ce 0.001512895 0.001886345 0.001867847 0.001658217 0.001875594
w4.ce 0.002340536 0.002637327 0.002736944 0.002252872 0.002848985
w5.ce 0.001329015 0.001553925 0.001654385 0.001654023 0.001806535
w6.ce 0.001326739 0.001595000 0.001487649 0.001417510 0.001581388

> dim(corrected_pi)
[1] 1300    5
```

So, is there a way I can assign all the pi values to the corresponding species in just one column of the data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all `pi` values for a species in one column using `nest` from the `tidyr` package. Then use `merge` to join the new `pi` table with `vervetdf`. Here, we assume that you did not yet create the `NA` column for `vervetdf$pi` as the `merge` will do that for you:

```
library(tidyr)
new.pi <- nest(data.frame(species=factor(levels(vervetdf$species), levels=levels(vervetdf$species)), t(corrected.pi)), -species, .key=pi)
result <- merge(vervetdf, new.pi, by="species", sort=FALSE)
```

Given the limited (only `6` rows of `corrected.pi`) data you posted:

```
print(result)
##                              species     ucla_id                  country Gender                                                                           pi
##1                 Chlorocebus sabaeus   A8516_M_2                 Barbados      M 0.002306475, 0.002620691, 0.001867847, 0.002736944, 0.001654385, 0.001487649
##2 Chlorocebus pygerythrus pygerythrus   AG23_F_10                 Tanzania      F 0.002408772, 0.002779025, 0.001886345, 0.002637327, 0.001553925, 0.001595000
##3 Chlorocebus pygerythrus pygerythrus AG5417_F_10                 Tanzania      F 0.002408772, 0.002779025, 0.001886345, 0.002637327, 0.001553925, 0.001595000
##4                Chlorocebus tantalus  AGM126_F_1 Central African Republic      F 0.002086117, 0.002599817, 0.001658217, 0.002252872, 0.001654023, 0.001417510
##5                Chlorocebus tantalus  AGM127_F_1 Central African Republic      F 0.002086117, 0.002599817, 0.001658217, 0.002252872, 0.001654023, 0.001417510
##6                Chlorocebus tantalus  AGM129_F_1 Central African Republic      F 0.002086117, 0.002599817, 0.001658217, 0.002252872, 0.001654023, 0.001417510
```

Notes:

1. `new.pi` is a data frame with 5 rows, one for each of your species.
2. `new.pi` is a data frame with two `columns`:

   - `species`: which is a factor created using the levels of the vervetdf$species column. This allows us to join the two tables later.
   - `pi`: which is created by `nest`. Note that `nest` creates a new column, named after the `.key` parameter, that is a list of values from the columns that are nested. The first argument to `nest` is the data frame from which columns are to be nested. Here, we construct a temporary data frame that is the `species` column plus all the rows of `corrected.pi` (i.e., `t(corrected.pi)`). Then we select all columns except for the `species` column to nest (i.e., `-species`)